# Search by Date range and Keyword in ElasticSearch Nest client?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a search that will filter by both the given keyword, as well as a given date range using the Nest client.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<mdl.Event>(s => s
                .From(0)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m
                        .Query(search.Text))));
```

This returns as expected, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to filter by date with it. Is there a simple addition like .Date(d => d) or another way I can make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `DateRange` function (standing for the `range` DSL query). You need to combine both constraints using bool queries

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<mdl.Event>(s => s
            .From(0)
            .Query(q => 
                 q.Match(m => m.Query(search.Text)) && 
                 q.DateRange(r => r
                      .Field(f => f.StartedOn)
                      .GreaterThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01))
                      .LessThan(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01))
                 )
            )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Do you think you could take a look at another question for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217570/running-query-versus-a-query-search-query-via-nest-client

Comment: do you think you could take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278229/elasticsearch-nest-query-returning-null-values-for-every-field I'm lost at what's happening here