# Running Query versus a Query Search Query via Nest client?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and am writing basic search queries. I want to be able to search the full text field for a keyword. I understand that this can be done using query search query, but I am unclear on how this is done using the Nest client.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<mdl.Event>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Query(search.Text))
                && q
                .DateRange(r => r
                    .Field(f => f.CreatedTimeStamp)
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(search.From)
                    .LessThanOrEquals(search.To))));
```

This is the code I have. Basically, I am trying to search for some text between some date,, but I believe above it is not searching the body for code. Is there a way I can easily change this query so that it is searching the whole body? Or is it already doing that and I'm unware?

I am searching for events in cluster. An example of an event might look like:

```
{
  "text": "string",
  "includeExecution": true,
  "processIds": "string",
  "statuses": [
    "string"
  ],
  "space": "string",
  "from": "2021-09-17T01:40:03.796Z",
  "to": "2021-09-17T01:40:03.796Z",
  "take": 0,
  "skip": 0,
  "orderBy": "string",
  "orderByDescending": true
}
```

In my case, I want to be able to search for the word "string" and have this result come up (because "string" exists on space)

Comment: Can you provide the mapping of the field you're searching on?

Comment: @Val what does that mean exactly? Sorry

Comment: Can you show a sample document and what you're trying to search?

Comment: @Val does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `QueryString` query like this. That will search for `search.Text` in all fields of your documents.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<mdl.Event>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .QueryString(qs => qs
                    .Query(search.Text))
                && q
                .DateRange(r => r
                    .Field(f => f.CreatedTimeStamp)
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(search.From)
                    .LessThanOrEquals(search.To))));
```

Comment: Thank you again. Do you think you could take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247467/invalid-nest-response-built-from-a-unsuccessful-low-level-call-on-post-using